# assertEquals fails when comparing two identical lists

Tags: java, list, collections, junit

I am running the following test to check if the two lists are identical:

```
public void testSortInputStream() throws IOException {
        field = "User ID";
        streamSorter.sort(inputStream, outputStream, comparator);

        Reader actualCSVReader = new BufferedReader(outputStreamToInputStreamReader(outputStream));
        Reader expectedCSVReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(expectedStream));

        List<CSVRecord> actualCSVRecords = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(actualCSVReader).getRecords();
        List<CSVRecord> expectedCSVRecords = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(expectedCSVReader).getRecords();

        Assert.assertEquals(expectedCSVRecords, actualCSVRecords);
    }
```

Strangely enough, the assert fails with the following message:

```
 expected: java.util.ArrayList<[CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping=null, recordNumber=1, values=[10, Ruby, Wax, ruby, Employee, 12-12-2014 08:09:13]], CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping=null, recordNumber=2, values=[3, David, Payne, Dpayne, Manager, 23-09-2014 09:35:02]]]> 


 but was: java.util.ArrayList<[CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping=null, recordNumber=1, values=[10, Ruby, Wax, ruby, Employee, 12-12-2014 08:09:13]], CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping=null, recordNumber=2, values=[3, David, Payne, Dpayne, Manager, 23-09-2014 09:35:02]]]>
```

However, if you compare the two lists, they are absolutely identical. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does `CSVRecord` implement `equals`?

Comment: Good question.... let me check

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html

Comment: Nope. But there must be a generic way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`CSVRecord`'s javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html) that you linked, `CSVRecord` does not override `equals(Object)` - it inherits the default implementation from `java.lang.Object`. Hence, you can't rely on it for equality checks, including nested checks, such as `List<CSVRecord>`. It isn't perfect, but a dirty trick you could use is to convert your `CSVRecord`s to string, and compare their representations:

```
List<String> actualCSVRecords =  
    CSVFormat.RFC4180
             .parse(actualCSVReader)
             .getRecords()
             .stream()
             .map(Object::toString)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> expectedCSVRecords =
     CSVFormat.RFC4180
             .parse(expectedCSVReader)
             .getRecords()
             .stream()
             .map(Object::toString)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

Assert.assertEquals(expectedCSVRecords, actualCSVRecords);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain this bit:

.stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @user3727540 I'm using Java 8's streams syntax to convert a `List<CSVRecord>` to `List<String>` - I stream the list, convert each `CSVRecord` to a string using the `toString` method, and then collect the stream back to a list. You can look at [the Documentation (beta) entry](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams#t=201701041231042876386) for some background.

Comment: Many thanks! You solution actually works and it is very elegant.